# How to properly write query SELECT'ing multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

please advise on query below. I want to select multiple tables. entryId is from table stockTracking. I bet i should use JOIN or smt.. Cheers!

```
$updateEntryId  = $_GET["entryId"];
$query          = "SELECT * 
                   FROM stockTracking, loggers, boxes 
                   WHERE entryId ='$updateEntryId'";
$result         = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

table

```
boxes|boxId boxQuantity boxName
        2           10      CL64

loggers | loggerId loggerQuantity loggerName
              2         10           34242342
stockTracking| entryId  time        destination reference
              2        timestamp        Paris       1312
```

I have updated query to following, however what wrong with my WHERE statement?
As i add WHERE entryId='$updateEntryId' if fails to display any results

```
$updateEntryId  = $_GET["entryId"];
$query          = "SELECT * 
               FROM stockTracking
               JOIN loggers
               ON entryId=loggerId 
               JOIN boxes
               ON boxId=entryId 
               WHERE entryId='$updateEntryId'";
```

Comment: Not sure i understand the question. I want to sort by id wich is in table stockTracking.

Comment: I'd go with JOIN. I don't think smt is an SQL function.

Comment: But do i have to? I mean, i dont see why i should have a common field in all of them, since they consist of different data. I just want to use id from stockTracking table. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. You should perform a `JOIN` operation among-st the tables like below. replace `some_column` in below sample sql code with your actual column name on which you have relationship between the tables

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM stockTracking s
JOIN loggers l ON s.some_column = l.some_column
JOIN boxes b ON b.some_column = s.some_column
WHERE s.entryId ='$updateEntryId'
```

Comment: What if they dont have relationship among each other..? I am having hard time figuring relationship between them..

Comment: @DotOnI, you can even perform `JOIN` on common columns between the tables. post your table structure for the tables and can help further

Comment: I have added existing tables into my first post, please see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$updateEntryId  = $_GET["entryId"];
$query          = "SELECT * 
               FROM stockTracking s
               JOIN loggers l
               ON s.entryId=l.loggerId 
               JOIN boxes b
               ON b.boxId=s.entryId 
               WHERE s.entryId='".$updateEntryId."'";
```

Join the tables as stated by @rahul but should be done in proper manner .. cheers!

Comment: it does not display any, other then that it fails on line: "if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)"

Comment: $result= mysqli_query($connection, $query);                                           
  <?php var_dump($result); ?>
  object(mysqli_result)[2]
  public 'current_field' => int 0
  public 'field_count' => int 13
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => int 0
  public 'type' => int 0

Comment: try to use SELECT s.* in place of SELECT *

Comment: when you run query in phpmyadmin do you get any results?

Comment: No, i do not. "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."

Comment: Do you have any data in the tables that you are joining?

Comment: Yes i do, each table has 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
Problem was in `$updateEntryId=$_GET["entryId"]`;
It had no results, since as search bar was showing `http://stock/edit.php?id=2`, it was looking for `$_GET["id"]` and not `$_GET["entryId"]`.